# API request Retrofit Jetpack Compose

Tags: wordpress, retrofit, http-status-code-401, jetpack

I have an API which sends a JSON response with status code 401 but I do not receive that response if status code is 401, if my API developer changes the status code to 200, I can easily get that response.

I have tried the expected response type in Response retrofit provides but that also does not work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.